# how do screenshot / screen grab programs work on POSIX systems running X?

Tags: x11, xorg, screenshot

1. How do [screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot) programs such as [gnome-screenshot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Screenshot) or [xfce4-screenshooter](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfce4-screenshooter) get their data?
2. How can they access a stream of the monitor/screen's 2d pixel matrix?
3. Is it possible to stream only a specific monitor's data on a multi-monitor setup? I want to pipe the data into a program I am trying to write, which will be a FOSS program/script for multicomputer/monitor setups.

Answer (score 5):

For questions 1 and 2, I will take a *wild* guess that they are accessing the root window's drawable through [RootWindow (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rootwindow), then using [XGetImage (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xgetimage) to copy the root window's pixel data somewhere to process it further (e.g. dumping it to a PNG).

These man pages may help:
[XOpenDisplay (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xopendisplay),
[DefaultScreen (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/defaultscreen),
[RootWindow (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rootwindow),
[XGetImage (3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xgetimage)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249669/how-do-take-a-screenshot-correctly-with-xlib) on StackOverflow.

As for question 3, if Xinerama is used, there will be more than one screen present, and the application can obtain informations about the position and size of each screen, which will again be useful to select the area to copy with `XGetImage(...)`.

Of course this all assumes you are using Xlib. I hear there is a better alternative called [XCB](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/), but personally I have never used it so far.